# Autologin with Satellizer

Tags: javascript, angularjs, satellizer

I implemented satellizer in the login controller.
However, what about auto login? What is best practices?

The call to auth is now inside the LoginCtrl:

```
$auth.login(credentials)
    .then(function(data) {
        //Save username and userid in local storage
        if(data.data !== undefined && data.data.user_name !== undefined &&     data.data.user_id !== undefined){
            window.localStorage['user_name'] = data.data.user_name;
            window.localStorage['user_id'] = data.data.user_id;
        }
        //Save email and password in local storage for autologin
        window.localStorage['user_email'] = credentials.email;
        window.localStorage['user_password'] = credentials.password;
        $state.go('home', {});
    })
    .catch(function(response) {
        alert("error");
    });
```

When a user is on another page, if token has expired, the he will not be able to access pages that require authentication.
I dont want him to login again. So in each other controller, if request to some protected resource fails, my idea is to autologin him. So Im putting auth.login in all of these controllers. Which looks as a bad choice.

What should I do? Create a service? Both for login and autologin? Is this best practices?